# UIPageViewController black screen on iPad when loaded in landscape

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, landscape, uipageviewcontroller

I'm developing a UIPageViewController based app which works both on iPhone and iPad. With the iPhone there are no problems, since the spine location of the controller is always set to UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin. In the iPad however, I need to set the spine location to UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid when the device orientation is set to Landscape.

I have a strange issue only when i Load the controller in Landscape orientation, the following video will explain the situation..
[YouTubeVideo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDYpD_rbWCg&feature=youtube_gdata_player)

As you can see, everything works perfectly when i load the controller in portrait and also after i rotate the device when i load in landscape.

I really can't figure out where is the problem. Here is the code I use to load the controllers:

```
    if (chapter.controllers) {

        currentPage = [chapter bookPageForCharIndex:location];

        //Load the correct controller for the bookmark page
        NSArray *array = nil;
        if (currentPage >= 0 && currentPage < chapter.controllers.count) {
            if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation])  && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                [self setDoubleSided:YES];
                if (chapter.controllers.count > currentPage+1) {
                    array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[chapter.controllers objectAtIndex:currentPage],[chapter.controllers objectAtIndex:currentPage+1],nil];
                }
                else {
                    array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[chapter.controllers objectAtIndex:currentPage],[[[LSBookPageViewController alloc]init]autorelease],nil];
                }
            }
            else {
                array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[chapter.controllers objectAtIndex:currentPage],nil];
            }
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
        [self playSoundsOfChapter:chapter];

        if (isRestarting) {
            [self setViewControllers:array
                           direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse 
                            animated:YES 
                          completion:nil];
            isRestarting = NO;
        }
        else {
            [self setViewControllers:array
                           direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward 
                            animated:YES 
                          completion:nil];
        }
        [array release];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the first else clause. You should set a breakpoint after checking for device orientation and device, and step through the code. I would guess that your `array` comes back empty.

Comment: Something strange is happening here.. In that scope the array is full (2 elements), but if I check this way: 

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"%d",[[self viewControllers]count]);
} 

I get a 0...

Comment: Here we are, when the controller is loaded in landscape, the spineLocation is not set to "Mid". Even if i call [self pageViewController:pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]] the spine location is not set properly(the method is executed)...

Comment: @Lolloz89 I just wanted to say that checking [self viewControllers] is VERY useful, thank you for suggesting it because it helped me track down my problem.